# 403 Forbidden for S3 static files on Django app running on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, boto3

This is a quite perplexing problem I have. First off, you can check out the website yourself with this [link](https://shrouded-woodland-96165.herokuapp.com/3). As you can see, the stylesheet isn't loading from my S3 bucket, it's returning a 403 Forbidden error. Which doesn't make any sense because just to be sure before asking the question, I altered the permissions on the file and, all of it's parent directories to "Everyone can open/download". What's more is that everywhere else in the website, this problem doesn't occur. I don't even know where to start looking.

Does anyone have any idea, why something like this would occur? Could it be a problem with the app itself? I don't think so, because the index works exactly as expected and it's in the same directory and loads the static files the same way. It may be a problem with Boto3? I know the question is vague, I'm just hoping someone can point me in the correct direction to where the problem lies.

Comment: Check whether the file is in the correct path https://shrouded-woodland-publications.s3.amazonaws.com/static/BlogPostAssets/styles/blogPostStyle.css

Comment: It is in the correct path, but to make sure I double checked. Turns out the path is case-sensitive. The first letter of the folder name was capitalized. Which after taking care of, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, turns out the path to a file in S3 is case sensitive. The first letter of the file's parent folder was capitalized which threw the browser off. So there you go. Paths are case-sensitive.